# Remove horizontal scroll bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using a facebook like button on my web page. I need it to align at the right side of the page. But there is a horizontal scroll bar displaying.

Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u4kMs/

I couldn't find out what causes this. How to fix this?

Comment: There is no scroll bar, maybe you set a wider width than your monitor.

Comment: I have set width less than my monitor width. If i remove he facebook like button the horizontal scroll bar disappears.

Comment: Same here, no scrollbar on the button, your container is just too wide for the window.

Comment: smth like this? http://jsfiddle.net/u4kMs/5/ and scroll bar is because of `<div style="width:980px;">` change width to smaller and there wont be scroll bar

Comment: The scroll bar is not displayed in the button. The page has the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: If you want them inline without scroll bar http://jsfiddle.net/u4kMs/9/ use `float:left` for "sample content" div and `float:right;` for fb share button, and `<div style="width:980px;">` take out the width or make it smaller!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The scrollbar appears because the content is too wide for your screen.

Just omit the width on the `div` element, it will auto-expand to 100% of it's parent. Floating the facebook button to the right like you already did should then align the button correctly without scrollbar.

If you don't get a satisfying solution you can still declare `overflow:hidden` on the containing div to supress the scrollbars.

This would be the result: http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/u4kMs/8/

Answer (score 30):

to disable scroll, try something like;

```
.your_div_class{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the frame is too small for the width that you have set on the top div

```
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:980px;">
```

So when this is on your web page yo shouldn't get the horizontal scroller. If you do, then consider changing the above width

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/u4kMs/7/) and remember to put the "right-aligned" div ***before*** the left-aligned div, even the right div have to be "after" graphically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

rtl has a problem most times, (with me special with

`<body dir="{{(App::isLocale('ar') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr')}}">`

in laravel and the only solution is

`body{ overflow-x: hidden; }` but be careful with inside element is fitted well